# Make PUT call to external website using Rest Template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, put, gemfire

I'm currently trying to make a PUT call to my Gemfire Cache test enviroment
https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/rest_apps/put_update_data.html

I've tried following a template like so

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/data/putdata/{id}/{name}";
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("id", "100");
    map.put("name", "Ram");
    Address address = new Address("Dhananjaypur", "Varanasi","UP");
    restTemplate.put(url, address, map);
}
```

Where in my case would it look something like this?

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = "gemfire.com/gemfire-api/v1/{region}/{key};
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("region", "1");
    map.put("key", "testKey");
    restTemplate.put(url, "testStringtoPut", map);
}
```

This template leads into a 404 not found error for me, 
can someone provide an insight on a proper method of doing this?

Comment: is your application running in port 8080? If so check the endpoints and configuration of the `spring-rest` app

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way, it should work

```
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(address.toString());

String url=http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/data/putdata/100/"Ram"

ResponseEntity <String> response= template.exchange(url,HttpMethod.PUT,request,String.class);
```

Comment: still 404, but also i believe it only takes in JSON to PUT, gemfire doesnt accept other formats

Comment: you can add content type in headers. HttpHeaders=new Httpheaders();  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);  and now HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(address.toString(), headers);  This way you are only sending JSON Data.

Comment: also check the url again

Comment: added content type headers, but now im getting 405 method not allowed

Comment: https://www.1and1.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/error-405-method-not-allowed-explanation-and-solutions/ . 405 may have many causes. Please go through the link.

Comment: you are hitting the desired url. gemfire may not be letting you in due to security reasons.

Comment: yeah its not letting me in but i disabled certificate validation to test, bad solution but it's letting me access it. I think my error was bad JSON format, will continue giving it a try